# Archlinux nfs is shutting down immediately

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, nfs, arch-linux

I want to setup an NFS server so I setup NFS as in the [Archlinux tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS) with two mount points:

```
[jenia@jenia ~]$ sudo exportfs -arv
point 1
point 2
point 3
exportfs: /etc/exports [3]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "192.168.1.0/24:/srv/nfs".
  Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
  NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x

exportfs: /etc/exports [4]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "192.168.1.0/24:/srv/nfs/music".
  Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
  NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x

exporting 192.168.1.0/24:/srv/nfs/music
exporting 192.168.1.0/24:/srv/nfs
```

But nothing is responding on `nfs://192.168.1.0/srv/nfs`:

```
[jenia@jenia ~]$ sudo nfs-ls nfs://192.168.1.0/srv/nfs
Failed to mount nfs share : nfs_mount_async failed. Failed to start connection. Failed to start connection. connect() to server failed. Network is unreachable(101)
[jenia@jenia ~]$
```

When I do `journalctl --follow -xn` and restart nfs daemon `systemctl restart nfs-server.service` I get:

```
Nov 17 20:36:21 jenia sudo[45585]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by jenia(uid=0)
Nov 17 20:36:21 jenia systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS being skipped.
-- Subject: A start job for unit auth-rpcgss-module.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A start job for unit auth-rpcgss-module.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 2142.
Nov 17 20:36:21 jenia systemd[1]: Stopping NFS server and services...
-
```

Also doing `systemctl status nfs-mountd nfsdcld nfs-idmapd` everything is running successfully.

Doing `systemctl status nfs-server` says:

```
[jenia@jenia ~]$ sudo systemctl status nfs-server.service
* nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-11-17 20:42:09 EST; 3s ago
    Process: 45946 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 45947 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 45947 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]: exportfs: /etc/exports [3]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "192.168.1.0/24:/srv/nfs".
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]:   Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]:   NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]: exportfs: /etc/exports [4]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export "192.168.1.0/24:/srv/nfs/music".
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]:   Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]:   NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]: point 1
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]: point 2
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia exportfs[45946]: point 3
Nov 17 20:42:09 jenia systemd[1]: Finished NFS server and services.
[
```

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to connect to an NFS server at 192.168.1.0. This is not likely to be your NFS server's actual IP address. Use the correct IP address.

Comment: No but the `nfs-server` is not running

Comment: @JeniaIvanov Yes it is. Now you just need to connect to it.

Comment: Yea. You're right. :) Turned out to be listening on `192.168.1.123` :) Thanks